# Bundle does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" ... When adding routes from bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I am getting this error:

```
 Bundle "bundlename" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" method of your "App\Kernel.php" file?
```

I have activated my bundle in bundle.php

In mine bundle I have routes.yaml file

```
route_name:
path: /crop
controller: bundlename\UploadImagesBundle\Controller\Crop\CropController::crop
options:
expose: true
```

When I am trying to add following to *config/routes.yaml* in mine project I get the error.

```
    app_crop:
  # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
  resource: '@bundlename/UploadImagesBundle/Resources/config/routes.yaml'
```

Comment: Make sure you have the full case sensitive bundle name `resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources...`  And I am pretty sure you don't need the `bundlename` prefix.  The vendor name should be part of the bundle's class name.  Something like `VieUploadImagesBundle`.

Comment: This was the solution! I thougt I already tried that. Thanks!